# SQL tables design layout

Tags: sql, data-modeling

I'm trying to design my database with very basic tables and I am confused on the CORRECT way to do it.

I've attached a picture of the main info, and I'm not quite sure how to link them.  Meaning what should be a foreign key, or should some of these tables include of LIST<> of the other tables.

[image: layout]

UPDATE TO TABLES
[image: updated tables]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your requirements, You are right about the associative table

1. Client can have multiple accounts And Accounts can have multiple clients
      Then, Many (Client) to Many (Account)
   So, Create an associate table to break the many to many relationship first. Then join it that way
2. Account can have only one Manager
   Which means One(Manager) to Many(Accounts)
   So, add an attribute called ManagerID in Accounts
3. Account can have many traedetail
   Which means One(Accounts) to Many(TradeDetails)
   So, add an attribute called AccountID in TradeDetails

Comment: thanks. I put a picture of updated tables.  Does that look right?

Comment: You are right! This works fine, But still, I feel **[Mapping ClientAccount].[Id]** is not making any sense, instead we can remove that and we can make both ClientID and AccountID as Primary Key as well as Foreign Key in [Mapping ClientAccount]. Other than that everything looks perfect.

Comment: yes I agree [Mapping_ClientAccount].[Id] is kind of useless.  I thought you can only make 1 column a PK.  How would I make both ClientID and AccountID the PK as you state above?

Comment: Yes, we should have only one primary key in a table, but we can have multiple columns as a single primary key.. 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp

Comment: CREATE TABLE Persons
(
P_Id int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
CONSTRAINT pk_PersonID PRIMARY KEY (P_Id,LastName)
)
Note: In the example above there is only ONE PRIMARY KEY (pk_PersonID). However, the VALUE of the primary key is made up of TWO COLUMNS (P_Id + LastName)

Comment: think I understand now... the part where you say CONSTRAINT is combining P_Id and LastName and using that combination as the PrimaryKey.  Do I understand that correct?

Comment: At the same time, you should know one more thing, Basically what the primary key does, it won't allow duplicates and etc.. 
Now adding 2 columns as a Primary Key will do the same,

For Ex.. 
ClientID  AccountID     Status
  1           1         Allow
  1           2         Allow
  1           1         Fails

Comment: To sum up, ClientID and AccountID should not same in the second row

Comment: yes that would work for me.  The combination of ClientID and AccountID should not be repeated more than once.. thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117362/discussion-between-muthaiah-pl-and-solarissf).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on whether you are looking to have a normalized database or some other type of design paradigm.  I recommend doing some reading on the concepts of database normalization and referential integrity.

What I would do is make tables that have a 1 to 1 relationship such as account/manager into a single table (unless you can think of a really good reason not to).  Add Clientid as a foreign key to Account.  Add AccountID as a foreign key to TradeDetail.  You are basically setting up everything as 1 to many relationships where the table that has 1 record for the id has the field as a primary key and the table that has many has it as a foreign key.

Comment: Account can have many Client as well, so intermediary table is needed to break the many-to-many relationship.

Comment: You are right.  I didn't read the original post carefully enough. An intermediate table is needed.

Comment: I added an intermediate table in the picture above.  And yes, after I googled normalized database that is what I want.

Comment: appreciate the tip on normalizing db @Eric